# Why is List.ItemCount reporting zero items when there are 90+ visible on Sharepoint?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm writing a script that clears out all of a list's existing items before writing new ones to it. Unfortunately, I can't figure out why my List is reporting that it has zero items in it when I can see all 90+ of them via Sharepoint. Here's the code I'm running:

```
function uploadDataFromCSV($_ctx, $_listName)
{
    Write-Host "[$_listName]"

    $list = $_ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($_listName)
    if($list.Exists){write-host "yes"}
    $list.ItemCount # Always returns 0

    # Clear all the items from the list if the flag has been set
    if($OverwriteItems)
    {
        Write-Host 'Deleting contents of list'
        $list.ItemCount
        $listItems = $list.Items
        # Delete from last to first because %REASONS%
        for($index = $listItems.Count-1; $index -gt -1; $index--)
        {
           $listItems[$index].Delete()
        }
        Write-Host 'List has been reset'
    }

    Write-Host 'Reading CSV file'
    $csv = Import-Csv "$csvDir\$_listName.csv"
    $headers = $csv | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | %{$_.name}

    $itemsAdded = 0
    foreach($line in $csv)
    {
        $itemCreateInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation
        $newItem = $list.AddItem($itemCreateInfo)

        # Map each value in the line to its corresponding header
        $headers | % {
            $statement = [scriptblock]::Create('$newItem["{0}"] = $line.{0}' -f $_)
            $statement.Invoke()
        }
        $newItem.Update()
        $itemsAdded++
    }
    Write-Host' Importing items'
    #Add the items to the list
    #$_ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    Write-Host $itemsAdded 'items imported'
}

#Load .NET CSOM modules
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

$site_url = "https://url.goes/here"
$username = "user@domain.com"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 'gibberishPassword'

#Set up the context and set its credentials
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($site_url)
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password)
$ctx.Credentials = $credentials

uploadDataFromCSV $ctx "TableName"
```

I need the number of items in the list so I can iterate through and delete them all one-by-one (I know I know, deleting the list and restoring from template isn't an option). I know I'm grabbing the correct list because the items I add further down the script are inserted correctly - after the script runs I can refresh Sharepoint and see the newly added items in addition to the list's existing items.

Why is `$list.ItemCount` saying there's nothing in the list?

Comment: Does the account which you are using have access to the list? I've had that problem before.

Comment: @DeanOC I would assume so, unless reading list items and writing items to a list are separate permissions?

Comment: Can you access the list via your browser using those credentials?

Comment: @DeanOC yes, they're the same credentials I use to log into Sharepoint

Comment: If you run PowerShell, and cut/paste your script into it, can you get any other properties of the $list object? To make sure that it has been set properly execute `if($list.Exists){write-host "yes"}`. If you don't get `yes`, then you've got bigger issues than the ItemCount being zero.

Comment: @DeanOC I didn't get a `yes`...which is weird because I know I'm writing to it. I've edited my question to include additional code, maybe I'm doing something wrong with how I'm querying the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with SharePoint CSOM in order to retrieve client object like [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list(v=office.15).aspx) or its properties like [List.ItemCount property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.itemcount(v=office.15).aspx) it has to be requested using [ClientContext.ExecuteQuery method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext.executequery(v=office.15).aspx).

In your case since List object has not been loaded, [List.ItemCount property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.itemcount(v=office.15).aspx) is not initialized, the following example demonstrates how to get  [List.ItemCount property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.itemcount(v=office.15).aspx):

```
$list = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName) #get List object
$context.Load($list) #prepare query to load List object 
$context.ExecuteQuery() #submit query to request List Object
$itemsCount = $list.ItemCount #ItemCount property is loaded now and returns list items count
```